# Pocketsphinx Unity Not Recognizing Buffers in ProcessRaw

Tags: unity-game-engine, pocketsphinx

Problem: I am getting no results 95% of the time and the rest is just not accurate single-words from pocketsphinx.

Could this be due to low recording volume?

So far:

Pocketsphinx is initialized with default hmm, lm and dict included with it. The setup code is: (no crashes, no problems whatsoever).

```
g_NPCController.Debug("Initializing internal decoder ... ");

    string directoryPrefix = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar +
        "Pocketsphinx" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "model";
    string hmmDir = directoryPrefix + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "en-us" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "en-us";
    string dictDir = directoryPrefix + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "en-us" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "cmudict-en-us.dict";
    string lmDir = directoryPrefix + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "en-us" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "en-us.lm.bin";
    Config c = Pocketsphinx.Decoder.DefaultConfig();

    if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
    {
        c.SetString("-hmm", "/sdcard/Android/data/edu.cmu.sphinx.pocketsphinx/files/sync/en-us-ptm");
        c.SetString("-dict", "/sdcard/Android/data/edu.cmu.sphinx.pocketsphinx/files/sync/cmudict-en-us.dict");
        c.SetString("-lm", "/sdcard/Android/data/edu.cmu.sphinx.pocketsphinx/files/sync/en-us.lm.bin");
    } else if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer) {
        // TODO - outta luck for now
    }
    else
    {
        if (g_NPCController.DebugMode)
            c.SetString("-logfn", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "Pocketsphinx" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "current.log");
        c.SetString("-hmm", hmmDir);
        c.SetString("-dict", dictDir);
        c.SetString("-lm", lmDir);
    }
    //c.SetString("-keyphrase", "hello world");
    c.SetFloat("-kws_threshold", 1e-30);
    c.SetFloat("-samprate", (int) g_NPCAudioListener.SampleFrequency);
    c.SetInt("-nfft", 2048);
    g_Decoder = new Pocketsphinx.Decoder(c);
    g_Decoder.StartUtt();
    g_NPCController.Debug("... local decoder initialized.");
```

Then, within a coroutne in the main thread, buffers are processed in one shot. Buffers can be from 2600 to 12800 bytes long each. The following code is called every frame:

```
                while (!buffer.Closed)
                    yield return null;

                g_NPCAudioListener.AudioBufferQueue.Dequeue();

                byte[] audio = new byte[buffer.CurrentBuffer16.Count * sizeof(short)];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer.CurrentBuffer16.ToArray(), 0, audio, 0, audio.Length);

                g_Decoder.ProcessRaw(audio, audio.Length, false, consumed == buffer.CurrentBuffer.Count);

                if (g_Decoder.Hyp() != null) {
                    g_DictationResults.Enqueue(g_Decoder.Hyp().Hypstr);
                    g_Decoder.EndUtt();
                    g_Decoder.StartUtt();
                }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I am very close to make it work - this would be a huge help for my project. Am I missing some configuration parameters?

With init log:

```
INFO: pocketsphinx.c(152): Parsed model-specific feature parameters from C:\Users\fgera\Development\Git\Computer-Graphics\Motional.AI\Pocketsphinx\model\en-us\en-us/feat.params
Current configuration:
[NAME]                  [DEFLT]         [VALUE]
-agc                    none            none
-agcthresh              2.0             2.000000e+00
-allphone
-allphone_ci            yes             yes
-alpha                  0.97            9.700000e-01
-ascale                 20.0            2.000000e+01
-aw                     1               1
-backtrace              no              no
-beam                   1e-48           1.000000e-48
-bestpath               yes             yes
-bestpathlw             9.5             9.500000e+00
-ceplen                 13              13
-cmn                    live            current
-cmninit                40,3,-1         40,3,-1
-compallsen             no              no
-dict                                   C:\Users\fgera\Development\Git\Computer-Graphics\Motional.AI\Pocketsphinx\model\en-us\cmudict-en-us.dict
-dictcase               no              no
-dither                 no              no
-doublebw               no              no
-ds                     1               1
-fdict
-feat                   1s_c_d_dd       1s_c_d_dd
-featparams
-fillprob               1e-8            1.000000e-08
-frate                  100             100
-fsg
-fsgusealtpron          yes             yes
-fsgusefiller           yes             yes
-fwdflat                yes             yes
-fwdflatbeam            1e-64           1.000000e-64
-fwdflatefwid           4               4
-fwdflatlw              8.5             8.500000e+00
-fwdflatsfwin           25              25
-fwdflatwbeam           7e-29           7.000000e-29
-fwdtree                yes             yes
-hmm                                    C:\Users\fgera\Development\Git\Computer-Graphics\Motional.AI\Pocketsphinx\model\en-us\en-us
-input_endian           little          little
-jsgf
-keyphrase
-kws
-kws_delay              10              10
-kws_plp                1e-1            1.000000e-01
-kws_threshold          1e-30           1.000000e-30
-latsize                5000            5000
-lda
-ldadim                 0               0
-lifter                 0               22
-lm                                     C:\Users\fgera\Development\Git\Computer-Graphics\Motional.AI\Pocketsphinx\model\en-us\en-us.lm.bin
-lmctl
-lmname
-logbase                1.0001          1.000100e+00
-logfn                                  C:\Users\fgera\Development\Git\Computer-Graphics\Motional.AI\Pocketsphinx\current.log
-logspec                no              no
-lowerf                 133.33334       1.300000e+02
-lpbeam                 1e-40           1.000000e-40
-lponlybeam             7e-29           7.000000e-29
-lw                     6.5             6.500000e+00
-maxhmmpf               30000           30000
-maxwpf                 -1              -1
-mdef
-mean
-mfclogdir
-min_endfr              0               0
-mixw
-mixwfloor              0.0000001       1.000000e-07
-mllr
-mmap                   yes             yes
-ncep                   13              13
-nfft                   512             2048
-nfilt                  40              25
-nwpen                  1.0             1.000000e+00
-pbeam                  1e-48           1.000000e-48
-pip                    1.0             1.000000e+00
-pl_beam                1e-10           1.000000e-10
-pl_pbeam               1e-10           1.000000e-10
-pl_pip                 1.0             1.000000e+00
-pl_weight              3.0             3.000000e+00
-pl_window              5               5
-rawlogdir
-remove_dc              no              no
-remove_noise           yes             yes
-remove_silence         yes             yes
-round_filters          yes             yes
-samprate               16000           1.600000e+04
-seed                   -1              -1
-sendump
-senlogdir
-senmgau
-silprob                0.005           5.000000e-03
-smoothspec             no              no
-svspec                                 0-12/13-25/26-38
-tmat
-tmatfloor              0.0001          1.000000e-04
-topn                   4               4
-topn_beam              0               0
-toprule
-transform              legacy          dct
-unit_area              yes             yes
-upperf                 6855.4976       6.800000e+03
-uw                     1.0             1.000000e+00
-vad_postspeech         50              50
-vad_prespeech          20              20
-vad_startspeech        10              10
-vad_threshold          3.0             3.000000e+00
-var
-varfloor               0.0001          1.000000e-04
-varnorm                no              no
-verbose                no              no
-warp_params
-warp_type              inverse_linear  inverse_linear
-wbeam                  7e-29           7.000000e-29
-wip                    0.65            6.500000e-01
-wlen                   0.025625        2.562500e-02

INFO: feat.c(715): Initializing feature stream to type: '1s_c_d_dd', ceplen=13, CMN='batch', VARNORM='no', AGC='none'
INFO: acmod.c(162): Using subvector specification 0-12/13-25/26-38
INFO: mdef.c(518): Reading model definition: C:\Users\fgera\Development\Git\Computer-Graphics\Motional.AI\Pocketsphinx\model\en-us\en-us/mdef
INFO: mdef.c(531): Found byte-order mark BMDF, assuming this is a binary mdef file
INFO: bin_mdef.c(336): Reading binary model definition: C:\Users\fgera\Development\Git\Computer-Graphics\Motional.AI\Pocketsphinx\model\en-us\en-us/mdef
INFO: bin_mdef.c(516): 42 CI-phone, 137053 CD-phone, 3 emitstate/phone, 126 CI-sen, 5126 Sen, 29324 Sen-Seq
INFO: tmat.c(149): Reading HMM transition probability matrices: C:\Users\fgera\Development\Git\Computer-Graphics\Motional.AI\Pocketsphinx\model\en-us\en-us/transition_matrices
INFO: acmod.c(113): Attempting to use PTM computation module
INFO: ms_gauden.c(127): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: C:\Users\fgera\Development\Git\Computer-Graphics\Motional.AI\Pocketsphinx\model\en-us\en-us/means
INFO: ms_gauden.c(242): 42 codebook, 3 feature, size:
INFO: ms_gauden.c(244):  128x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(244):  128x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(244):  128x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(127): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: C:\Users\fgera\Development\Git\Computer-Graphics\Motional.AI\Pocketsphinx\model\en-us\en-us/variances
INFO: ms_gauden.c(242): 42 codebook, 3 feature, size:
INFO: ms_gauden.c(244):  128x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(244):  128x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(244):  128x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(304): 222 variance values floored
INFO: ptm_mgau.c(475): Loading senones from dump file C:\Users\fgera\Development\Git\Computer-Graphics\Motional.AI\Pocketsphinx\model\en-us\en-us/sendump
INFO: ptm_mgau.c(499): BEGIN FILE FORMAT DESCRIPTION
INFO: ptm_mgau.c(562): Rows: 128, Columns: 5126
INFO: ptm_mgau.c(594): Using memory-mapped I/O for senones
INFO: ptm_mgau.c(837): Maximum top-N: 4
INFO: phone_loop_search.c(114): State beam -225 Phone exit beam -225 Insertion penalty 0
INFO: dict.c(320): Allocating 138623 * 32 bytes (4331 KiB) for word entries
INFO: dict.c(333): Reading main dictionary: C:\Users\fgera\Development\Git\Computer-Graphics\Motional.AI\Pocketsphinx\model\en-us\cmudict-en-us.dict
INFO: dict.c(213): Dictionary size 134522, allocated 1014 KiB for strings, 1677 KiB for phones
INFO: dict.c(336): 134522 words read
INFO: dict.c(358): Reading filler dictionary: C:\Users\fgera\Development\Git\Computer-Graphics\Motional.AI\Pocketsphinx\model\en-us\en-us/noisedict
INFO: dict.c(213): Dictionary size 134527, allocated 0 KiB for strings, 0 KiB for phones
INFO: dict.c(361): 5 words read
INFO: dict2pid.c(396): Building PID tables for dictionary
INFO: dict2pid.c(406): Allocating 42^3 * 2 bytes (144 KiB) for word-initial triphones
INFO: dict2pid.c(132): Allocated 42672 bytes (41 KiB) for word-final triphones
INFO: dict2pid.c(196): Allocated 42672 bytes (41 KiB) for single-phone word triphones
INFO: ngram_model_trie.c(354): Trying to read LM in trie binary format
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(74): Initializing search tree
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(101): 790 unique initial diphones
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(186): Creating search channels
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(323): Max nonroot chan increased to 152144
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(333): Created 722 root, 152016 non-root channels, 53 single-phone words
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(157): fwdflat: min_ef_width = 4, max_sf_win = 25
INFO: cmn_live.c(120): Update from < 40.00  3.00 -1.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 >
INFO: cmn_live.c(138): Update to   < 95.43 -6.79 -5.30 -6.10 -10.80  2.20 -1.31 -0.54 -2.47 -3.11 -0.83  2.18  5.92 >
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1550):     1601 words recognized (18/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1552):   237595 senones evaluated (2700/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1556):   578857 channels searched (6577/fr), 49670 1st, 54325 last
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1559):     3042 words for which last channels evaluated (34/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1561):    18162 candidate words for entering last phone (206/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1564): fwdtree 18.25 CPU 20.739 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1567): fwdtree 14.14 wall 16.065 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(302): Utterance vocabulary contains 57 words
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(948):      692 words recognized (8/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(950):    83914 senones evaluated (954/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(952):   102603 channels searched (1165/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(954):     4800 words searched (54/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(957):     2171 word transitions (24/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(960): fwdflat 0.03 CPU 0.036 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(963): fwdflat 0.03 wall 0.033 xRT
INFO: cmn_live.c(120): Update from < 95.43 -6.79 -5.30 -6.10 -10.80  2.20 -1.31 -0.54 -2.47 -3.11 -0.83  2.18  5.92 >
INFO: cmn_live.c(138): Update to   < 92.77 -8.91 -9.40 -6.80 -11.46 -0.71 -2.89 -0.45  1.43 -3.17 -1.35  0.17  3.64 >
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1550):     4191 words recognized (37/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1552):   451300 senones evaluated (4029/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1556):  3011851 channels searched (26891/fr), 76495 1st, 179109 last
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1559):     8886 words for which last channels evaluated (79/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1561):   234585 candidate words for entering last phone (2094/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1564): fwdtree 28.91 CPU 25.809 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1567): fwdtree 18.27 wall 16.315 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(302): Utterance vocabulary contains 167 words
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(948):     2425 words recognized (22/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(950):   166879 senones evaluated (1490/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(952):   279618 channels searched (2496/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(954):    13084 words searched (116/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(957):     9930 word transitions (88/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(960): fwdflat 0.08 CPU 0.070 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(963): fwdflat 0.08 wall 0.074 xRT
INFO: ngram_search.c(467): Resized score stack to 200000 entries
INFO: ngram_search.c(459): Resized backpointer table to 10000 entries
INFO: cmn_live.c(120): Update from < 92.77 -8.91 -9.40 -6.80 -11.46 -0.71 -2.89 -0.45  1.43 -3.17 -1.35  0.17  3.64 >
INFO: cmn_live.c(138): Update to   < 93.21 -8.67 -8.88 -5.56 -10.87 -0.19 -2.78 -0.73  2.84 -3.07 -1.93  0.79  2.44 >
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1550):     6212 words recognized (97/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1552):   251244 senones evaluated (3926/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1556):  2124350 channels searched (33192/fr), 43302 1st, 190124 last
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1559):     9693 words for which last channels evaluated (151/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1561):   212658 candidate words for entering last phone (3322/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1564): fwdtree 13.48 CPU 21.069 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1567): fwdtree 9.23 wall 14.425 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(302): Utterance vocabulary contains 311 words
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(948):     3854 words recognized (60/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(950):   138888 senones evaluated (2170/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(952):   414216 channels searched (6472/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(954):    18404 words searched (287/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(957):    11245 word transitions (175/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(960): fwdflat 0.14 CPU 0.220 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(963): fwdflat 0.12 wall 0.187 xRT
INFO: cmn_live.c(120): Update from < 93.21 -8.67 -8.88 -5.56 -10.87 -0.19 -2.78 -0.73  2.84 -3.07 -1.93  0.79  2.44 >
INFO: cmn_live.c(138): Update to   < 93.41 -9.57 -8.47 -5.47 -10.06  0.42 -2.95 -1.82  2.57 -2.62 -0.98  1.79  2.24 >
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1550):     3858 words recognized (54/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1552):   236795 senones evaluated (3289/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1556):  1169796 channels searched (16247/fr), 40281 1st, 142488 last
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1559):     7030 words for which last channels evaluated (97/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1561):    72648 candidate words for entering last phone (1009/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1564): fwdtree 17.91 CPU 24.870 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1567): fwdtree 12.32 wall 17.115 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(302): Utterance vocabulary contains 155 words
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(948):     2938 words recognized (41/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(950):   111642 senones evaluated (1551/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(952):   229547 channels searched (3188/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(954):    10456 words searched (145/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(957):     6314 word transitions (87/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(960): fwdflat 0.08 CPU 0.109 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(963): fwdflat 0.08 wall 0.104 xRT
INFO: cmn_live.c(120): Update from < 93.41 -9.57 -8.47 -5.47 -10.06  0.42 -2.95 -1.82  2.57 -2.62 -0.98  1.79  2.24 >
INFO: cmn_live.c(138): Update to   < 93.74 -10.48 -8.87 -5.63 -9.42  0.32 -3.21 -2.07  2.21 -1.54 -0.68  1.97  1.85 >
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1550):     7019 words recognized (80/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1552):   325095 senones evaluated (3694/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1556):  1955385 channels searched (22220/fr), 58503 1st, 232252 last
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1559):    11334 words for which last channels evaluated (128/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1561):   115217 candidate words for entering last phone (1309/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1564): fwdtree 18.08 CPU 20.543 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1567): fwdtree 11.98 wall 13.615 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(302): Utterance vocabulary contains 365 words
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(948):     2632 words recognized (30/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(950):   176368 senones evaluated (2004/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(952):   522457 channels searched (5937/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(954):    23759 words searched (269/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(957):    13859 word transitions (157/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(960): fwdflat 0.11 CPU 0.124 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(963): fwdflat 0.11 wall 0.130 xRT
INFO: cmn_live.c(120): Update from < 93.74 -10.48 -8.87 -5.63 -9.42  0.32 -3.21 -2.07  2.21 -1.54 -0.68  1.97  1.85 >
INFO: cmn_live.c(138): Update to   < 93.53 -10.03 -8.85 -4.80 -8.58  0.32 -3.52 -2.14  2.91 -1.47 -0.63  2.22  1.90 >
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1550):      883 words recognized (21/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1552):   146888 senones evaluated (3416/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1556):   750300 channels searched (17448/fr), 25850 1st, 46629 last
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1559):     2323 words for which last channels evaluated (54/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1561):    53709 candidate words for entering last phone (1249/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1564): fwdtree 17.42 CPU 40.516 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1567): fwdtree 12.03 wall 27.979 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(302): Utterance vocabulary contains 53 words
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(948):      650 words recognized (15/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(950):    37862 senones evaluated (881/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(952):    45609 channels searched (1060/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(954):     2226 words searched (51/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(957):     1814 word transitions (42/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(960): fwdflat 0.02 CPU 0.036 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(963): fwdflat 0.02 wall 0.042 xRT
INFO: cmn_live.c(120): Update from < 93.53 -10.03 -8.85 -4.80 -8.58  0.32 -3.52 -2.14  2.91 -1.47 -0.63  2.22  1.90 >
INFO: cmn_live.c(138): Update to   < 92.82 -9.69 -8.69 -5.19 -8.84  0.28 -2.89 -2.53  2.95 -0.77  0.05  2.61  1.68 >
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1550):      868 words recognized (19/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1552):   165478 senones evaluated (3597/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1556):  1148658 channels searched (24970/fr), 30324 1st, 29845 last
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1559):     1763 words for which last channels evaluated (38/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1561):   103611 candidate words for entering last phone (2252/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1564): fwdtree 12.61 CPU 27.412 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1567): fwdtree 8.01 wall 17.409 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(302): Utterance vocabulary contains 46 words
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(948):      585 words recognized (13/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(950):    35815 senones evaluated (779/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(952):    37653 channels searched (818/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(954):     2052 words searched (44/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(957):     1642 word transitions (35/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(960): fwdflat 0.02 CPU 0.034 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(963): fwdflat 0.02 wall 0.043 xRT
INFO: cmn_live.c(120): Update from < 92.82 -9.69 -8.69 -5.19 -8.84  0.28 -2.89 -2.53  2.95 -0.77  0.05  2.61  1.68 >
INFO: cmn_live.c(138): Update to   < 93.42 -9.82 -8.43 -4.88 -8.43  0.13 -2.56 -2.49  3.26 -0.28  0.04  2.72  1.43 >
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1550):     6952 words recognized (67/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1552):   414969 senones evaluated (3990/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1556):  2748306 channels searched (26426/fr), 71316 1st, 227747 last
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1559):    11669 words for which last channels evaluated (112/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1561):   197819 candidate words for entering last phone (1902/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1564): fwdtree 14.70 CPU 14.138 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1567): fwdtree 10.16 wall 9.771 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(302): Utterance vocabulary contains 267 words
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(948):     4301 words recognized (41/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(950):   215433 senones evaluated (2071/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(952):   503454 channels searched (4840/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(954):    22257 words searched (214/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(957):    14100 word transitions (135/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(960): fwdflat 0.16 CPU 0.150 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(963): fwdflat 0.15 wall 0.146 xRT
INFO: cmn_live.c(120): Update from < 93.42 -9.82 -8.43 -4.88 -8.43  0.13 -2.56 -2.49  3.26 -0.28  0.04  2.72  1.43 >
INFO: cmn_live.c(138): Update to   < 93.27 -9.95 -7.95 -3.79 -7.90  0.07 -2.63 -2.50  3.61 -0.30 -0.63  2.60  1.69 >
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1550):     1560 words recognized (32/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1552):   174992 senones evaluated (3646/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1556):  1340415 channels searched (27925/fr), 30752 1st, 70997 last
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1559):     3334 words for which last channels evaluated (69/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1561):   135428 candidate words for entering last phone (2821/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1564): fwdtree 5.31 CPU 11.068 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1567): fwdtree 3.83 wall 7.975 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(302): Utterance vocabulary contains 99 words
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(948):     1259 words recognized (26/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(950):    61872 senones evaluated (1289/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(952):   107099 channels searched (2231/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(954):     4479 words searched (93/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(957):     3862 word transitions (80/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(960): fwdflat 0.05 CPU 0.098 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(963): fwdflat 0.04 wall 0.083 xRT
INFO: cmn_live.c(120): Update from < 93.27 -9.95 -7.95 -3.79 -7.90  0.07 -2.63 -2.50  3.61 -0.30 -0.63  2.60  1.69 >
INFO: cmn_live.c(138): Update to   < 93.46 -10.27 -7.86 -3.87 -7.63 -0.25 -2.72 -2.36  3.36 -0.15 -0.46  2.59  1.64 >
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1550):     3794 words recognized (53/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1552):   239815 senones evaluated (3331/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1556):  1394923 channels searched (19373/fr), 44549 1st, 127514 last
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1559):     6614 words for which last channels evaluated (91/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1561):   107867 candidate words for entering last phone (1498/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1564): fwdtree 23.55 CPU 32.704 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1567): fwdtree 15.71 wall 21.824 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(302): Utterance vocabulary contains 174 words
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(948):     2625 words recognized (36/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(950):   112676 senones evaluated (1565/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(952):   238159 channels searched (3307/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(954):    11272 words searched (156/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(957):     6236 word transitions (86/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(960): fwdflat 0.08 CPU 0.109 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(963): fwdflat 0.08 wall 0.110 xRT
INFO: cmn_live.c(120): Update from < 93.46 -10.27 -7.86 -3.87 -7.63 -0.25 -2.72 -2.36  3.36 -0.15 -0.46  2.59  1.64 >
INFO: cmn_live.c(138): Update to   < 93.46 -10.27 -7.86 -3.87 -7.63 -0.25 -2.72 -2.36  3.36 -0.15 -0.46  2.59  1.64 >
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(302): Utterance vocabulary contains 0 words
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(429): TOTAL fwdtree 179.72 CPU 24.721 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(432): TOTAL fwdtree 121.51 wall 16.713 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(176): TOTAL fwdflat 0.75 CPU 0.103 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(179): TOTAL fwdflat 0.73 wall 0.100 xRT
INFO: ngram_search.c(303): TOTAL bestpath 0.00 CPU 0.000 xRT
INFO: ngram_search.c(306): TOTAL bestpath 0.00 wall 0.000 xRT
```

Answer (score 1):

You have endianess issue when you convert 16-bit buffer to bytes here:

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer.CurrentBuffer16.ToArray(), 0, audio, 0, audio.Length);
```

You need to swap bytes

Comment: Hey Nikolay. Thanks for your answers. The system is little endian and as per the configuration `-input_endian           little          little` isn't pocketsphinx expecting little endian bytes? However, I am not using `Buffer.BlockCopy` any more, just passing directly the bytes from the buffer.